# JavaScript engine development book or article

Tags: javascript, c++

im looking for a book to learn more about the development of a JavaScript engine (if that exist), i would appreciate any info about this topic, thanks beforehand.

-
Or any articles about Javascript Engine development! :)

Comment: I'm not sure that that many people develop JavaScript engines for a book about that topic to be worth it.

Comment: Read the ES5 spec, read the v8 source, read the spidermonkey source, read the dragon book.

Comment: ive read the dragon book and the spec, but the last one is too messy and the Dom documentation is horrible!!

Comment: Let us know how your project goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not c++, but here's a Douglas Crockford article on [building a simplified Javascript parser **with** Javascript.](http://javascript.crockford.com/tdop/tdop.html)

However, he explains that the parser methodology is more (only?) suited to functional languages, and wouldn't work in procedural languages (like c++).

However, he does discuss a number of aspects of implementing a JS parser that might point you in some directions.

There is a series of posts on [building a JS interpreter in Python.](http://renesd.blogspot.com/2010/06/lets-make-shit-javascript-interpreter.html)

There is also a [php Javascript parser and tokenizer.](http://timwhitlock.info/blog/2009/11/14/jparser-and-jtokenizer-released/)

Answer (score 5):

The V8 open source Javascript engine written by Google and used in Chrome is [here](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) and you could learn a ton from studying that.

I rather doubt you will find a book on the subject and I am not aware of one.

Comment: Why the downvote without a comment?  The OP said they would "appreciate any info about this topic" so I supplied some.  Any open source reference implementation and all the associated documentation, comments and wiki sure seems relevant to me.

Comment: i doubt that too, but i still need the info.